# When should I create new queue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

After iOS 4.3 we can create a new queue as serial or concurrent. Before that we use an existing queues as concurrent and created as serial. So now when should I create new instead using existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to put some block of code onto an arbitrary queue, then just use one of the system ones.

If you want to have a queue for specific reasons - such as using a queue for thread safe access to a property, then create a specific queue for that.